# Simplest way to add a field to an existing document with javascript and html in a couchdb document?

Tags: javascript, json, forms, couchdb

I am new to html forms and submitting data and i need some help with adding fields to a document in couchdb.
The starting document is:

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "_rev": "7-4951bf45b301a3d836f2658e92758d30",
   "ndStatus": 1,
   "ndNumber": 1,
   "ndRegion": "atiq",
   "ndName": "kaxum",
   "group": "11,12,25,14"
}
```

I want to add the numbers a user submits on the group field when a user submits a form on the client side.
I have tried looking at several resources on how to do this but they seem to make it pretty complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it. That is what [update function](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers) were created for.

Answer (score -1):

Couchdb makes some trade-offs in the name of scalability. One of these is you must always write the entire document at once. I am not quite sure what you mean when you say you want to

> add the numbers a user submits on the group field

Regardless, you will need to fetch the document from couchdb, make any changes, and then save it back with your updates and a rev. If you are using node.js and the [cradle](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle) library it looks like

```
var id = '1' // this is a weird value for _id but okay...
var db = {} // this should be a cradle db connection
db.get(id, function (err, res) {
  var doc = res.json
  var rev = doc._rev
  doc.group = 10 // new group value, change this as you need
  db.save(id, rev, doc, function(err, reply) {
    if (err) {
      console.dir('error saving document', err)
      return
    }
    console.dir('document saved correctly', reply)
  })
})
```